# I have space invidator game and the bullet doesn't want to move

Tags: python, pygame

In pygame I have a space invaders game and when I press space to fire the bullet it shows on the screen but it doesn't move.

```
import pygame
# Bullet
bulletIMG = pygame.image.load("bullet.png")
bulletIMG = pygame.transform.scale(bulletIMG, (30, 30))
bulletY = 500
bulletYChange = 10
bulletState = "ready"

# fire bullet function
def fireBullet(x, y):
    global bulletState
    bulletState = "fire"
    win.blit(bulletIMG, (x + 10, y - 10))

running=True
while running:
 for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             running = False
         # checking if key pressed
         if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                fireBullet(playerX, playerY)
  # Bullet Movement
  if bulletState == "fire":
        fireBullet(playerX, playerY)
        bulletY -= bulletYChange
  pygame.display.update()
```

[this is a photo of the bullet when it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTxWV.png) It's the yellow thing

Comment: You never use the value of `bulletY` anywhere, that's why it's not moving. Shouldn't it be `fireBullet(playerX, bulletY)` in your `if bulletState == "fire"` statement? Also, if you keep the X as `playerX`, the bullet is going to move side to side along with the player, so really you should be keeping track of the bullet's `X` position separately. When you initially fire the bullet, it makes sense to me to set `bulletX` and `bulletY` to the player's `X` and `Y`, but then always just use the bullet `X` and `Y` positions subsequently.

Comment: `fireBullet(playerX,playerY)` draws at the player position, not the bullet position.

Comment: @RandomDavis Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `pygame.display.update()` at the end of the while loop.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't write it here I will edit it now but I wrote it in my code